# Get the value of a key value pair in an object in an array

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the values of the attribute `value` in a new array. For the following example, the result would be: `["Plumbing", "Electrical", "Fencing"]`

```
const arr = [
  { label: "Plumbing", value: "Plumbing" },
  { label: "Electrical", value: "Electrical" },
  { label: "Fencing", value: "Fencing" },
];
```

I mean something like: `newArray = currentArray forEach Get Value`

Comment: use `arr.map(o => o.value)`

Comment: The answer is below. You should accept is answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get the value of all `label` using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const arr = [
  { label: "Plumbing", value: "Plumbing" },
  { label: "Electrical", value: "Electrical" },
  { label: "Fencing", value: "Fencing" },
];

const result = arr.map((o) => o.value);
console.log(result);
```

You can also destructure to make it more succinct

```
const result = arr.map(({ value }) => value);
```

```js
const arr = [
  { label: "Plumbing", value: "Plumbing" },
  { label: "Electrical", value: "Electrical" },
  { label: "Fencing", value: "Fencing" },
];

const result = arr.map(({ value }) => value);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hm... I would not recommend reduce for the OP in this case. Map is the correct functor for this case, anyway, and reduce might confuse the OP

Comment: That's why I removed it before your comment. Thanks for the suggesion. hehe

Comment: You're right that's why I upvoted yours.
In my language we say "Why make it simple when you can make it complicated" :)

Comment: Anyway, this is a clear duplicate guys, let's go easy on the answers

Answer (score 0):

You can add your values to a new array using `forEach` like so :

```js
const arr = [
  { value: "Plumbing", label: "Plumbing" },
  { label: "Electrical", value: "Electrical" },
  { label: "Fencing", value: "Fencing" },
];

var newArr = []
arr.forEach(e => newArr.push(e.value))

console.log(newArr)
```

Or like @decpk said in comment you could simply use `map()` like so

```js
const arr = [
  { value: "Plumbing", label: "Plumbing" },
  { label: "Electrical", value: "Electrical" },
  { label: "Fencing", value: "Fencing" },
];

var newArr = arr.map(e => e.value)

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: why to use `forEach` when you have `map` that returns result in new array by default.